# Social Network post preview widget in Laravel app

Tags: php, facebook, laravel, twitter, linkedin-api

I made sourcing tool for my Online Assessment/ATS platform. That tool can schedule posts on varius job boards and social networks.

I'm trying to add an option that user can preview his Facebook, Twitter and LinkedIn post before publishing it.

Is it possible to get some kind of widget for these social networks or I need to make my own widget based on theirs design?